# String concatenation in AWS Glue Athena?

Tags: string-concatenation, aws-glue, presto, amazon-athena

I need to find a string concatenation function in AWS Glue inside GROUP BY, so far tried

```
SELECT CONCAT('wo', 'rd');
```

for which I need concatenation inside GROUP BY, written in meta language:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field_word WITH SEPARATOR '>' ORDER BY Order1) FROM myData GROUP BY ID;

SELECT STRING_AGG(field_word WITH SEPARATOR '>' ORDER BY Order1) FROM myData GROUP BY ID;
```

but the earlier do not work.

**How can I concatenate strings inside AWS Glue athena?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [`array_agg`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) with [`array_join`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_join):

```
presto> SELECT array_join(array_agg(e), ',', 'NULL')
     -> FROM (VALUES 'wo', 'rd') t(e);
 _col0
-------
 wo,rd
(1 row)
```